# How can I add a roof over the existing Deck?

Tags: roof, deck, decking, cover

I know how to build a cover, I just don't know how to attach it to the existing deck.

Something like this:
[image]

Comment: We need more information (or photos) to give you a specific recommendation. In general, you'd be looking at attaching support posts to your deck rail posts, adding a ledger to your house near the roof and a lateral beam across the posts, then joists from the ledger to beam supporting your cover.

Please edit your question to include links to a diagram or photos of your deck, and we can edit the photos into the post and give you more specific guidance on attaching a roof.

Comment: Vote to close, not enough info and no updates.

Comment: What can I use to attach a 4x4 to an existing deck?